# ST_Segmentize - segmentation and duplicates

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I did a segmentation on a layer of lines and then I transformed this segments to point dividing the line in 5 parts indepentently of his lengh. The problem I have, is that some of them, insted of segmenting in 5 parts, segment in more than 5.

The query I used:

```
SELECT
id,
ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText((geom_point).geom)), 3857) as geom_points
FROM (SELECT
    id,
    ST_DumpPoints(ST_Segmentize((geom),(st_length(geom)/5))) as geom_point
FROM sel_test) as punts
;
```

I think that this happend becouse of the point in the vertices that intersect with one or more lines, these ones have more than one id. I want to avoid this but i don't know how.

I post a image where you can see the problem representated:

[image: duplicated_points]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_Segmentize` only ever **adds** vertices (it does not remove or replace them), and only if the distance between **consecutive vertices** is larger than the given threshold.

If it's *Point*s you want derive them with `ST_LineInterpolatePoint`, e.g.:

```
SELECT id,
       ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, n*0.2) AS geom_point
FROM   sel_test
CROSS JOIN
       GENERATE_SERIES(0, 5) AS n
;
```

This will get you **6 equally spaced *Point*s** per line, representing 5 equal length segments, including start and end point.

---

If it's segments (*LineString*) you want, derive them with `ST_LineSubstring`, e.g.:

```
SELECT id,
       ST_LineSubstring(geom, n*0.2, (n+1)*0.2) AS geom_point
FROM   sel_test
CROSS JOIN
       GENERATE_SERIES(0, 4) AS n
;
```

This will generate **5 equal length segments (*LineString*s)** per line, including all vertices that were present in the original *LineString* (-> *substrings*).